# Django: Keep same URL after form POST

Tags: django

Good day SO, I am a beginner in Django and I have a quick question with Form submission and redirecting. I have been following a guide and am using function-based views as of now.

The main problem I have now is that after form submission, the URL changes from http://127.0.0.1:8000/projects/1/ to http://127.0.0.1:8000/projects/1/updateReport

How can I make it such that my URL, after form submission, goes back to http://127.0.0.1:8000/projects/1/ (without the /updateReport/). Thank you very much for your help!

Here are my urls:

```
url(r'^(?P<project_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.projectView, name='projectView'),
url(r'^(?P<project_id>[0-9]+)/updateReport/$', views.updateReport, name='updateReport')
```

Here are my views:

```
def projectView(request, project_id):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, id=project_id)
    reportSet = project.report_set.all()
    context = {
        'project': project,
        'reports': reportSet
    }
    return render(request,'projectMgmt/projectView.html',context)

def updateReport(request, project_id):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, id=project_id)
    sys_msg = "Report Updated!"

    #Increment Report Version
    reportSet = project.report_set.all()
    if reportSet.last():
        version = reportSet.last().reportVersion + 1
    else:
        version = 1 #New Report for project

    #New Report Text (name="reportText" from textarea in page)
    newText=request.POST['reportText']

    try:
        newReport = Report(project=project, reportVersion=version, reportText=newText)
        newReport.save()
    except:
        sys_msg="Error!"

    context = {
        'project': project,
        'reports': reportSet,
        'sys_msg': sys_msg
    }

    return render(request, 'projectMgmt/projectView.html',context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line to be a redirect to the url view you want to render: see [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

```
return render(request, 'projectMgmt/projectView.html',context)
```

To this

```
return redirect('projectView', project_id=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
```

> 1. By passing the name of a view and optionally some positional or keyword arguments; the URL will be reverse resolved using the
>      reverse() method:

```
def updateReport(request, project_id):
    ...
    return redirect('projectView', project_id=1)
```

> 2 . By passing a hardcoded URL to redirect to:

```
def updateReport(request, project_id):
    ...
    return redirect('/proects/'+ project_id + '/')
```